# How to display the questions with their answers in this nested GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I developed a simple Quiz Engine web-based application similar to the one explained in the ASP.NET website. The application should show different kind of questions such as multiple choice question with single answer or multiple answers.I am struggling now with the query that will show the question with its possible choices (either two choices or 4 or 5 choices). I have the following database design:

```
Questions Table: QuestionID, Question, QuestionOrder, AnswerExplanation
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description
QuizContent Table: ID, QuizID, QuestionID, AnswerID, isCorrect
```

*(isCorrect is a flag that refers to the correct answer of that question)*

I started by implementing it as a nested GridViews as suggested by someone here in the StackOverFlow. But now I don't know how to retrieve the questions with its possible answers only and then click on a next button to go to the other question. **So could you please help me in modifying this?**

My ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        DataKeyNames="QuestionID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionID" HeaderText="QuestionID" 
                                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="QuestionID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Question" HeaderText="Question" 
                                SortExpression="Question" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionOrder" HeaderText="QuestionOrder" 
                                SortExpression="QuestionOrder" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerExplanation" HeaderText="AnswerExplanation" 
                                SortExpression="AnswerExplanation" />
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:GridView ID="AnswersGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                                    DataKeyNames="AnswerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AnswerID" HeaderText="AnswerID" 
                                                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AnswerID" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Answer" HeaderText="Answer" 
                                                SortExpression="Answer" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
                                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Quiz2ConnectionString %>" 
                                                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Answers]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Quiz2ConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Questions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now, I have to come up with a query that can show any kind of question with its possible answers or choices (either 2 or 4 or 6 choices), so **how to do that?**

NOTE: Should I have QuizID as SessionParameter in my design as shown in the ASP.NET code?

Comment: First thing u are not a new asp.net developer :P

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then change PageSize=1 on parent Gridview. This will display only one row of parent GridView. Which is probably the questions Gridview. Also change AllowPaging=true.
oh... you seem to be very new. The query you have written is not correct. Study Sql and learn .net parameterized queries. In case you use the Master-Child relationship as you did then the child grid will use the SelectedDatakey.Value to provide to the child query.
" 
                                                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Answers] where QuestionId=@QuesionId">

you also have to include QuestionId in the Answers table for foreign key relationship. YOu seem very new first study. databases and query then you will be alittle at ease.